# SVN Connection Not Successful

Tags: svn, osx-mountain-lion

I am getting the following message when attempting to connect to our company's SVN repository - the same error occurs whether I try from the OSX command line or Eclipse.

Any ideas on where to troubleshoot?

I can access from other similar computers and others in my team do not have any problem - this issue started occurring on my MacBook Pro yesterday afternoon (no known changes were made to the OS prior to problem starting).

```
$ svn co http://example.ca/cwl/tags/app
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://example.ca/cwl/tags/app': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://example.ca)*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem on MBP running 10.7.5. Some other guys are reporting a similar problem at
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4280660  and 
[SVN Error when connecting from MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/472084/svn-error-when-connecting-from-macbook)

The svn+ssh connection and https connections work all ok. My other machine, running the same OS version does not have the problem.

An interesting thing is that I tried to run svn on a Ubuntu inside a virtualbox. It is experiencing the same results: svn ls http:// does not work; svn ls https:// works

Do you use Cisco AnyConnect 3.1 VPN? A note at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808500/svn-could-not-read-status-line-error -on-checkout suggests that the culprit could be the Cisco VPN client. I've recently upgraded to Cisco AnyConnect 3.1, and at about the same time svn ls http:// stopped working.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I did the following and it solved my problem and helped me unblock the issue. The web security module is causing this issue. So I had to uninstall it.

1. Open up the terminal and go to `cd /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin`.
2. Inside `bin` folder there is an uninstall script for web security module, `websecurity_uninstall.sh`
3. `sudo ./websecurity_uninstall.sh`

That’s it. My SVN is back working again, and right now all the things work fine.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue in combination with Cisco AnyConnect 3.1.
For us the problem seems to be the Web security plugin of AnyConnect. After uninstallation of AnyConnect (sudo /opt/cisco/..../bin/vpn_uninstall.sh + any other uninstall.sh script) we reinstalled AnyConnect just with the option "VPN" selected. Afterwards it worked.