# SVN Error when connecting from MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, svn, osx-mountain-lion

This is drying me nuts for last 5 days!!!

Out of the blue 5 days ago, SVN access from my MacBook Pro failed: I cannot access any SVN (i.e. not in our University or open source projects etc).

The error obtain when performing 'svn co', or any other svn commands is shown below. This is same message is obtained irrespective of the svn repository (i.e. it is something due to my Macbook)

svn co http://anonsvn.internet2.edu/svn/i2mi/branches/GROUPER_1_6_BRANCH/

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://anonsvn.internet2.edu/svn/i2mi/branches/GROUPER_1_6_BRANCH': ***Could not read status line: connection was closed by server*** (http://anonsvn.internet2.edu)

Comment: Update 'svn co' for 'https' URLs are working; the error is only for 'http' URLs. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: No - I am not using a proxy. In a moment of paranoia, I also had thought that there was a malware running a proxy on my MacBook Pro - based on looking at 'Netstat -a' there isn't anything suspicious running.

Answer (score 1):

I lost a few too many hours working through this issue and trawling forums for an answer.

Just in case anybody else is facing this issue, I found a workable solution in this forum post: [Super User - SVN Connection Not Successful](https://superuser.com/a/579485).

In summary, uninstall the Cisco Any Connect web security module. This approach worked for me with Cisco Any Connect Client 3.1.x for Apple Mac OS X 10.9.x